# Cannot start my WCF service while try to establish the connection inside service start

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I want to host a WCF service (using TCP) so I wrote this code:

```
ServiceHost myServiceHost = null;

// Create the binding.
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
//binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
//    TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;

// Create the URI for the endpoint.
Uri netTcpUri = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8008/MyService");

// Create the service host and add an endpoint.
myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), netTcpUri);
myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WcfServiceLibrary1.IMyService), binding, "");

// Open the service.
myServiceHost.Open();
```

This code works fine in a console application between computers in my network.

Now I created a Windows service project, define the service as `LocalSystem` and this is my service start/stop:

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    ServiceHost myServiceHost = null;

    public MyService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (myServiceHost != null)
            myServiceHost.Close();

        // Create the binding.
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
        //binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
        //    TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;

        // Create the URI for the endpoint.
        Uri netTcpUri = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8008/MyService");

        // Create the service host and add an endpoint.
        myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), netTcpUri);
        myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WcfServiceLibrary1.IMyService), binding, "");

        // Open the service.
        myServiceHost.Open();
        //Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
        //Console.ReadLine();

        // Close the service.
        //myServiceHost.Close();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (myServiceHost != null)
        {
            myServiceHost.Close();
            myServiceHost = null;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I put my connection creation code inside my service start.

Now after I successfully installed the service, I get this error while try to start it from windows services:

> Service on local computer started and stopped some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs

I try several times and received again and again this error.

I also try to remove the connection creation and try to install the service and start without this code and now the service started so it seems that something is wrong here and I don't know why (don't forget that this code works under console project so it's oblivious that this code is OK)

I try - catch and wrote the message inside a text file so now the service successfully started and this is the error message:

> The contract name 'WcfServiceLibrary1.IMyService' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'WindowsService1.MyService'.

`WcfServiceLibrary1` is my WCF service library project and `IMyService` exists and now my client cannot connect to my service although the service running

`MyService` and `IMyService`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }
}
```

Comment: Under what user is the service running? Maybe you need a namespace reservation for that URI and port.

Comment: Add a try/catch and log the exception in a file or something

Comment: As i mention under LocalSystem and all other options failed too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your Service class is MyService and also your WCF class is MyService, and you dont write full class name with namespace

```
myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfServiceLibrary1.MyService), netTcpUri);
myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WcfServiceLibrary1.IMyService),
```

or better way is rename WindowsService class...

Comment: see in servicemanager dose you'r service in running state?, if it is not, see windows event and see waht error occoered

Comment: The service not running in windows services

Comment: see Windows event log

Comment: Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: The contract name 'WcfServiceLibrary1.IMyService' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'WindowsService1.MyService'.
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.ValidateContractType(Type implementedContract, ReflectedAndBehaviorContractCollection reflectedAndBehaviorContracts)

Comment: because you Service class is MyService and also your WCF class is MyService, and you dont write full class name with namespace

Comment: what i need to change ?

Comment: just use myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfServiceLibrary1.MyService), netTcpUri); insted of myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), netTcpUri);